# awk print the column stored in an array and the previous column

Tags: awk

I have a piece of code that gives me the first column which starts with a certain pattern "gene" and it looks like that:

`awk -F '\t|;' '{for(i=9;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^gene=/){column=$i}} print column, column}' file`

and the file looks like this

```
contig_1    Prodigal:2.6    CDS 28  609 .   +   0   ID=PROKKA_00001;eC_number=1.-.-.-;inference=...;WayMoreColumns
contig_10   Prodigal:2.6    CDS 1031    1813    .   +   0   ID=PROKKA_00015;eC_number=4.2.1.-;gene=caiD_1;inference=...;WayMoreColumns
contig_10   Prodigal:2.6    CDS 1031    1813    .   +   0   ID=PROKKA_00015;eC_number=0.0.0.0;gene=caiD_1;inference=...;WayMoreColumns
contig_10   Prodigal:2.6    CDS 1832    2533    .   -   0   ID=PROKKA_00016;gene=gmuR;inference=...;WayMoreColumns
contig_10   Prodigal:2.6    CDS 43  1014    .   +   0   ID=PROKKA_00014;inference=...;WayMoreColumns
```

so some lines contain "gene", some not (I don't need those) but some give extra information in the previous column with the "eC_number".  As the same name of "gene" can be given (in rare cases) for different genes, this helps to identify which one it really is (made up example in line 2 and 3).

Is there an awkish way to say "column - $1" to print the previous column as well e.g. contains the array "column" this information? Or should I separately check for fields starting with "gene" and starting with "eC-number"?

As output it would be ok to have the previous column included, regardless whether it starts with "eC_number" or "ID", because cleaning up afterwards should be easy. But "gene" must be in the line, the eC_number alone is not helpful.

Desired output:

```
eC_number=4.2.1.-   gene=caiD_1
eC_number=0.0.0.0   gene=caiD_1
ID=PROKKA_00016 gene=gmuR
```

Thank you!

Comment: as a general solution, awk support $n to point field n. You can build variable n with any computation that suits your need, such as n = column - 1.

Comment: @setop: that sounds like a good advice, but with all my tries I only achieved something like "gene=caiD_1 - 1"...how do you use $n? I couldn't find a documentation on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a solution:

```
{ # for each line
    col = 0
    for(i=9; i<=NF; i++) { # search
        if($i~/^gene=/) {
            col = i
        }
    }
    if (col>0) { # if found
        print $col, $(col-1) # print column and previous one
    }
}
```

save it to "filter.awk" or something, and launch with :

```
awk -F '\t|;' -f filter.awk file
```

Comment: that works perfect, thanks. Could you explain what the different storing of matching columns `{col = i}` in your script and mine `{column = $i}` actually does? In my case it assigns it to a field and in yours it keeps a number, that is why you can perform i-1 on it?

Comment: Exactly. i is a number, so i-1 is meaningful. $i is the content of the ith field of the current record being processed.